# How should spec files be organised in a javascript application using MVC

Tags: backbone.js, jasmine

I would like to know your opinion about how you would organize the files/directores in a big web application using MVC (backbone for example).
I would make the following ( * ).  Please tell me your opinion.

---

( * )

```
js
js/models/myModel.js
js/collections/myCollection.js
js/views/myView.js
spec/model/myModel.spec.js
spec/collections/myCollection.spec.js
spec/views/myView.spec.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a good example how to organize your application to this link

[Backbone Jasmine examples](https://github.com/froots/backbone-jasmine-examples)

It looks more or less like your implementation.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I've traditionally organized my files. However, I've found that with larger applications it really becomes a pain to keep everything organized, named uniquely, etc. A 'new' way that I've been going about it is organizing my files by feature rather than type. So, for example:

```
js/feature1/someView.js
js/feature1/someController.js
js/feature1/someTemplate.html
js/feature1/someModel.js
```

But, oftentimes there are global "things" that you need, like the "user" or a collection of locations that the user has built. So:

```
js/application/model/user.js
js/application/collection/location.js
```

This pattern was suggested to me because then you can work on feature sets, package and deploy them using requirejs with relatively little effort. It also reduces the possibility of dependencies occurring between feature sets, so if you want to remove a feature or update it with brand new code, you can just replace a folder of 'stuff' rather than hunting for every file. Also, in IDE's, it just makes the files you're working on easier to find.

My two cents.

Edit: What about the spec files?

A few thoughts - you'll just have to pick the one that seems most natural to you I think.

1. You could follow the same 'feature folder' pattern with the spec files. The upside being that all of the specs are in one place. The downside is that now, much like what you're currently doing, you have to places for one feature's files.
2. You could put the specs in a 'spec' folder of the feature folder. The upside is that you now have actual packages that can be wrapped up in a single zip file with no chance of clobbering other work. It's also easier to find directly related files for writing tests - they're all in the same parent folder. The downside is that now your production code and test code is in the same folder, publishing it (possibly) to the world. Granted you'll probably end up compiling the production javascript down to one file at some point.. so I'm not sure that's much of an issue.
3. My suggestion - if this is a large application and you figure you're going to have a few hands touching the files, leave something like a 'package.json/yml/xml' file in the folder. In there, list out the production, spec, and any data files you need for testing (you can most likely write a quick shell script to do this for you). Then write out a quick script to look through your source folder for 'package.whateverYouChose' files, get the test files and then build your unit testing page with it. So, let's say you add another package.. run 'updateSpecRunner' or whatever you name the script, and it'll generate you another SpecRunner.html file (or whatever you named the file your running the specs on). Then you can manually test it in a browser, or automate it using phantomjs/rhino.

Does that make sense?

Comment: thanks, I will study your asnwer before to accept it... +1 thanks for your time